# What is the recommended way to set GET parameters on a Restlet request?

Tags: java, restlet

What is the recommended way of setting GET query parameters on a Restlet `Request` object?

I think I can see how to get them out of the request using `getQueryAsForm()`, but how do they get set in the first place?

At the moment, I am adding them manually to the URL using a `StringBuilder` and `java.net.URLEncoder`, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second attempt:

```
Reference reference = new Reference("http://127.0.0.1:8080/test"); 
reference.addQueryParameter("testParam", "testVal"); 
request.setResourceRef(reference);  
request.setMethod(Method.GET);
```

the addQueryParameter encodes the arguments automatically if needed.

Answer (score 0):

`request.getAttributes().get("key");`

See also the tutorial ([1.0](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.0/tutorial), [1.1](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.1/tutorial) or [2.0](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.0/tutorial)) on restlet.org

Comment: This doesn't work - this is code for *getting* an attribute from the request. I am interesting in *setting* a GET parameter (i.e. stuff after the & in the URL). I have read the tutorials, and they do not address this point as far as I can tell.